# Neo4j - How to merge/join parent -> children tree structure nodes

Tags: neo4j

i have a tree structure (project)-[:IS_PARENT_OF]->(projectChild)

A project can have multiple children, what i would like to do is a query that creates a virtual node that contains all the children of a parent.

So the node would have data like this :

```
parent: "project 1",
children:['cohort', 'protocol', etc...]
```

I tried this query

```
MATCH (p:Project)-[:IS_PARENT_OF]->(c)
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['Project'], {name: p.name, children: [c.name]}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

But i only get one child:

```
{
  "identity": -32,
  "labels": [
    "Project"
  ],
  "properties": {
"name": "project 1",
"children": [
      "Experimental design"
    ]
  }
}
```

Does someone know how to get multiple children in my vNode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to have tried a form of pattern comprehension, this is probably what you need:

```
MATCH (p:Project)
CALL apoc.create.vNode(
            ['Project'],      
            {
              name: p.name, 
              children: [(p)-[:IS_PARENT_OF]->(c) | c.name]
            }
     ) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

which would return an empty array  `[]` in case the project does not have children.

[image]

Comment: the second statement works better ;)

Comment: How would i do this recursively if the children have children of there own, with out knowing the final depth ?

To have somthing like this:
`{
  "identity": -32,
  "labels": [
    "Project"
  ],
  "properties": {
"name": "project 1",
"children": [
      "Experimental design",
      "cohort",
      children:[
          "Experimental design",
          "cohort",
           children:[
               "Experimental design",
                "cohort",
           ]
      ],
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: I'm not sure whether Neo4j will allow for nested structures in vNodes.  My question would be, why would you need those virtual nodes?

Comment: I have a tree structure with vuetify [tree structure vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#rounded)

I need to get the nested structure to display my tree structure correctly

Comment: did you look at https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.convert/apoc.convert.toTree/ ? which returns a nested json based on paths in a hierarchic structure.

Comment: That work grate Thanks so much !!